# Minimize variance python

Tags: python, variance, minimization

Not sure how to proceed with this. I have a list of numbers (a list of lists of numbers to be exact), but these number have an ambiguity: x, x+1 and x-1 are exactly the same thing for me. However, I'd like to minimize the variance of the list by changing the elements. Here's what i thought so far (with a sample list that I know it doesn't work):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

lst = [0.474, 0.122, 0.0867, 0.896, 0.979]
def min_var(lst):
    mode = np.mean(lst)
    var = np.var(lst)
    result = []
    for item in list(lst):
        if item < mean: # not sure this is a good test
            new_item = item + 1
        elif item > mean:
            new_item = item - 1
        else:
            new_item = item
        new_list = [new_item if x==item else x for x in lst]
        new_var = np.var(new_list)
        if new_var < var:
            var = new_var
            lst = new_list
    return lst
```

What the function does is add 1 to the 3rd element. However, the minimum variance occurs when you subtract 1 from the 4th and 5th. This happens because I'm minimizing the variance after each item, not allowing for multiple changes. How could I implement multiple changes, preferably without looking at all possible solutions (3**n if I'm not mistaken)?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You basically want to minimize `var((X + delta) % 1)` where X is your array of values. Try using a numerical solver like one you would find in `scipy.optimize`. In the end the optimal range you want the numbers in is `delta` to `delta + 1`, and you can add and remove integers from your numbers to ensure they're all in that range.

Comment: I was wrong about using `scipy.optimize`, but I've written a solution that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider this as a problem of finding the `delta` that minimizes `var((x + delta) % 1)` where `x` your array of values. Then you add and subtract integers from your values until they lie in the range `delta - 1 <= x[i] < delta`. This isn't a continuous function of `delta`, so you can't use solvers like in `scipy.optimize`. But we can use the information that the value of `var((x + delta) % 1)` only changes at each value of x, which means we only need to test each value in `x` as a possible `delta`, and find the one that minimizes the variance.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0.474, 0.122, 0.0867, 0.896, 0.979])

# find the value of delta
delta = x[0]
min_var = np.var((x - delta) % 1)
for val in x:
    current_var = np.var((x - val) % 1)
    if current_var < min_var:
        min_var = current_var
        delta = val

print(delta)

# use `delta` to subtract and add the right integer from each value
# we want values in the range delta - 1 <= val < delta
for i, val in enumerate(x):
    while val >= delta:
        val -= 1.
    while val < delta - 1.:
        val += 1.
    x[i] = val

print(x)
```

For this example, it finds your desired solution of `[ 0.474   0.122   0.0867 -0.104  -0.021 ]` with a variance of `0.0392`.

Comment: This appears to have worked, thanks. Never thought about the problem that way

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calculating the new var each time (O(n²)), you can see that when you affect an item from `x` to `x+u`, the var is affected like `u*(u/2+x-m-u/n)`.

So here is a quasi-linear time solution:

```
l=np.array([0.474, 0.122, 0.0867, 0.896, 0.979])
l.sort()
n=len(l)
m=np.mean(l)
print(l,np.var(l))
u=1 # increase little terms

for i in range(n):
   if u*(u/2+l[i]-m-u/n) < 0:
       l[i]= l[i] + u
       m = m+u/n # mean evolution
   else: u = -1  # decrease big terms

print(l,np.var(l))
```

and the run :

```
[ 0.0867  0.122   0.474   0.896   0.979 ] 0.1399936064
[ 1.0867  1.122   1.474   0.896   0.979 ] 0.0392256064
```